# Can't seem to set timeout to be more than 60s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to set a timeout to be 120s or more, but whatever I do they just timeout after 60s.

I've tried:

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    timeout: 120000,
    success: function(html){
        console.log("done");
    }
});
```

And

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 120000,
});
```

After 1 minute it'll just log this to the console:

```
GET website_url 504 (Gateway Time-out)

l.cors.b.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4

n.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.2.1.min.js:4

(anonymous function) @ jsfile.js:89

(anonymous function) @ jsfile.js:98
```

But all of them jsut show a timeout after 60s. I'm using Chrome if that makes a difference. Does anyone know why? My server still sends the data (I logged it to console when it sends) after like 80s or so, but AJAX timed out at 60s :\

Does anyone know why this is the case? Is there a built in limit for chrome or something?

Comment: you are sending a `jsonp` ?

Comment: Where you able to get the response?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the $.ajax [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), this is a covered topic.

This will work for u-

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    error: function(){
        // will fire when timeout is reached
    },
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    timeout: 120000 // sets timeout to 120 seconds
});
```

You can get and see what type of error was thrown by accessing the `textStatus` parameter of the error: `function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` option. The options are "`timeout`", "`error`", "`abort`", and "`parsererror`".

### Update

If u are getting Error 504, then

> This usually means that the upstream server is down (no response to the gateway/proxy), rather than that the upstream server and the gateway/proxy do not agree on the protocol for exchanging data.

Please have a look in **[here for detail](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E504.html)**.

U will understand why u are getting this error.

Comment: Yea it just says `Error 504, Gateway Timeout`. This is the `responseText`: `<html>
 <head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
 <body bgcolor="white">
 <center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
 <hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
 </body>
 </html>`

Comment: I managed to fix it. It was actually nginx that was timing out... 3 hours spent trying to fix this for nothing :(

Comment: @Rohinder I am having the same problem. I tried so many variables to increase timeout settings to 600 seconds in my nginx.conf but still not working. Any tips? What did you do? Is any javascript timeout code above required as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work for you

```
setTimeout( function() {
            $.ajax({                
                 url: URL
            //Your remaining code    
            })
        },120000)
```